# Graph library for Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, graph-theory

Is there any good library for some graph-app? I want to create nodes, add weighted edges, etc…

### EDIT

I need a graph (like on the image below) not a plot.

[image]

Comment: What kind of layout strategy do you need? I guess it is not the graphics part you are asking about because this is pretty simple to do with the good 2D library CoreGraphics already provide.

Comment: @Lothar maybe I'm now familiar with CoreGraphics that much, but it'll be nice to have some touch events handlers with vertex's connections. Some weight setup for edges, etc…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [GraphViz documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation/pdf/libguide.pdf) something like this should do the layout job:

```
- (void) testGraph {

    Agraph_t* G;
    GVC_t* gvc;
    gvc = gvContext();

    char* testGraph = "\
        digraph G {\
        subgraph cluster_c0 {a0 -> a1 -> a2 -> a3;}\
        subgraph cluster_c1 {b0 -> b1 -> b2 -> b3;}\
        x -> a0;\
        x -> b0;\
        a1 -> a3;\
        a3 -> a0;\
    }";

    G = agmemread((char*)testGraph);
    [self dumpGraph:G];

    gvLayout (gvc, G, "dot");
    NSLog(@"after layout:");

    [self dumpGraph:G];

    gvFreeLayout(gvc, G);
    gvFreeContext(gvc);

}

- (void) printNode:(Agnode_t*) node {
    NSLog(@"Node: %s {{%f,%f},{%f,%f}}",node->name,
          node->u.coord.x,
          node->u.coord.y,
          ND_width(node),
          ND_height(node));
}

- (void) dumpGraph:(Agraph_t*)graph {
    if (!graph)
        return;
    Agnode_t *n = NULL;
    Dict_t *dict = graph->nodes;
    for (n= dtfirst(dict); n ; n = dtnext(dict, n)) {
        [self printNode:n];
    }
}
```

Instead of using logNode: you should write some drawing code.

Log output:

```
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: a0 {{0.000000,0.000000},{0.000000,0.000000}}
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: a1 {{0.000000,0.000000},{0.000000,0.000000}}
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: a2 {{0.000000,0.000000},{0.000000,0.000000}}
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: a3 {{0.000000,0.000000},{0.000000,0.000000}}
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: b0 {{0.000000,0.000000},{0.000000,0.000000}}
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: b1 {{0.000000,0.000000},{0.000000,0.000000}}
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: b2 {{0.000000,0.000000},{0.000000,0.000000}}
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: b3 {{0.000000,0.000000},{0.000000,0.000000}}
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: x {{0.000000,0.000000},{0.000000,0.000000}}
GraphTest[32319:303] after layout:
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: a0 {{83.000000,250.000000},{0.750000,0.500000}}
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: a1 {{63.000000,178.000000},{0.750000,0.500000}}
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: a2 {{43.000000,106.000000},{0.750000,0.500000}}
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: a3 {{83.000000,34.000000},{0.750000,0.500000}}
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: b0 {{161.000000,250.000000},{0.750000,0.500000}}
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: b1 {{161.000000,178.000000},{0.750000,0.500000}}
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: b2 {{161.000000,106.000000},{0.750000,0.500000}}
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: b3 {{161.000000,34.000000},{0.750000,0.500000}}
GraphTest[32319:303] Node: x {{122.000000,322.000000},{0.750000,0.500000}}
```

Comment: Thanks for this; this has proven to be *extremely* helpful.  For one, I've discovered that you must create the gvContext *before* adding anything to the graph. Trying to create it later will cause some `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crashes, for whatever bizarre reason.

Answer (score 5):

It's not super Cocoa-friedly, but [Graphviz](http://graphviz.org) might either do a lot of what you need, or provide a good basis for your own efforts. (That is, the graphviz library can handle all the graph layout logic, and tell you where to put shapes which you then draw using your favorite graphics API. For example, this is how OmniGraffle's automatic layout feature works.)

Comment: This looks promising. It looks like Graphviz has a C API. Can you expound on how to interject your own drawing API?

Comment: Sorry, not really. This is more a case of "know of" than "know how" for me... actually trying it is one of those side projects I keep not having time to get into. :) They've got lots of documentation, though!

Comment: There's an open source Cocoa app called AutoGraf (source [here](http://autograf.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/autograf/)) that wraps GraphViz. It's very old, but it might provide some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you can restrict yourself to Mountain Lion and above, SceneKit seems to be a promising place to start. You'll have to manage the layout geometry yourself (actual positions of the nodes/edges), but you get hit testing and geometric primitives for free. Properties and textures are animatable: you can enlarge a node, darken an edge, change a number or color, all with your favorite Core Animation style calls.

Comment: In my particular case, I'm looking for the reverse: I want something to do the layout for me; I can handle the rendering myself.